# How to pass from an ODEs system to reactions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

I have the following system:
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=a_1+\frac{b_1x^n}{K_1^n+x^n}-gxy-d_1x,$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=a_2+\frac{b_2x^m}{K_2^m+x^m}-d_2y,$$

where $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2,K_1,K_2,g,d_1,d_2,n,m$ are real constants.

I would like to write the chemical reactions associated to these equations, but I do not know how to represent the fractions...

Comment: Are you familiar with Michaelis-Menten kinetics? Those fractions look very similar to the formulas appearing in Michaelis-Menten kinetics.

Comment: Thanks you for your comment! But in any case it did not really help me...

Comment: I guess what I mean is, assuming your constants are actually positive, you have a process generating $x$ from nothing, you have a process where $x$ and $y$ are consumed together, you have a process where $x$ is consumed by itself, a process where $y$ is consumed by itself. (Presumably these generate some products that are not being tracked). Then you have a process that generates $x$ from itself in a way that gets "saturated", i.e. as $x$ grows that rate increases but only up to $K_1^{-n}$.

Comment: You have a similar process that generates $y$ from $x$. These "saturation" type processes most commonly emerge in simple models, like Michaelis-Menten, for enzymatic kinetics.

Comment: Anyway, I think you will have trouble in writing down the reactions because your system, as written, is not "closed". At the very least it is not clear what the reactants of the $a_1,a_2$ reactions are, nor what the products of the $g,d_1,d_2$ reactions are, nor what is consumed by these "enzymatic"-looking reactions. $a_1,a_2$ could be understood by simply adding material directly into the system from the outside, but the others are not nearly so clear.